# Cloning all Completed AWS CloudFormation Stacks to a different region

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, aws-cli

Is there a way to script the cloning of all Completed CloudFormation stacks to another region from the current one? I checked the cloudformation 'list-stacks' and 'copy-stack' commands but was unable to figure out how to connect all the dots to make this happen.

Comment: what do you mean by CloudFormation tasks?

Comment: You have the CloudFormation templates that you have deployed, right? Why not just deploy them again, with a different region configured?

Comment: I actually want to make my whole setup reproducible by a single script and not just deploy the templates and delete them afterwards